# Google App Engine datastore supports only 200 indexes

Tags: google-app-engine

I am a newbie to app engine datastore. I am currently evaluating to migrate my existing webapp to app engine. 
I found that the hard limit for indexes is 200 for an application. 
So, i am really confused whether this constraint forces many limitations on the app engine datastore design.[ for eg. no of entity kinds, no of properties in an entity] etc.

Please advice me on this

Comment: 200 is big number for indexes. Hardly you will need that many.

Comment: please tell us where you found that hard limit?

Comment: You can check [link here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The answer you already got in Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/9282a15babd8c306), copied below, is a pretty good one.

> The number if indexes isn't affected by the number of properties on an
>   entity. It only has to do with the number of indexes for "complex queries"
>   that are needed in your application (i.e. Those in index.yaml). So the
>   number of indexes created automatically (by properties on indexes) are
>   probably only limited by your available storage and doesn't limit the number
>   of entities or properties on entities.
>
> See:
>   http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/indexconfig.html
>   http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass....

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic queries, one way to get around the limit of 200 indices is detailed at https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection

Answer (score 0):

The composite index quota might become an issue if your application grows large, as in number of features, not users. Here are some open tickets:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8305
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=287#c6

Note the comments regarding buying premium support to get around this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I'm unsure where you got the 200 number but that is not accurate.  To my knowledge there is no limit to the number of indexes per application, but there is a limitation to the number of indexes per model.  I believe there is a limitation of 5000 indexed properties on a model.

For more information on indexes you should get familiar with the [Queries and Indexes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html) section of the AppEngine documentation.

Comment: The figure is accurate - apps are limited to 200 indexes. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Datastore